# Check path equivalence using glib

Tags: c, string, path, filepath, glib

I need do check the equivalence of two filepaths using glib. I did it with Qt long time ago, via reduction paths. But I can't find similar instruments in glib.
Can someone suggest the common way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What kind(s) of equivalence do you mean, here? Specifically, how should symblic links be treated?

Comment: For example /home/user/file /home/user/dir/../file and file are the same (if $PWD=/home/user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For just "simple" canonicalization that resolves use of `.` and `..`, just create two `GFile` objects using the [GIO](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/) API's [`g_file_new_for_path()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GFile.html#g-file-new-for-path) function. Then compare the two files using [`g_file_equal()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GFile.html#g-file-equal).

Note that this relies on GIO doing simple canonicalization of the paths when you create the `GFile` objects; it won't resolve symbolic links. The documentation states:

> Using `GFile` as an identifier has the same weaknesses as using a path in that there may be multiple aliases for the same file. For instance, hard or soft links may cause two different `GFile`s to refer to the same file. Other possible causes for aliases are: case insensitive filesystems, short and long names on FAT/NTFS, or bind mounts in Linux. If you want to check if two `GFile`s point to the same file you can query for the `G_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ID_FILE` attribute. Note that `GFile` does some trivial canonicalization of pathnames passed in, so that trivial differences in the path string used at creation (duplicated slashes, slash at end of path, "." or ".." path segments, etc) does not create different `GFile`s.

So, you can do a two-step approach:

1. Check with `g_file_equal()`. If it says `true`, you're done.
2. Else query the `G_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ID_FILE` attribute and compare those.